# barssince function problem - tradingview pine

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading

The following code is working. But the 2nd doesnt work. Why ?

```
specificTime = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday and hour == 0 and minute == 0 and second == 0
countbar = barssince(specificTime)
plot(countbar)
```

The following code doesn't work. I don't know why. Please help.

```
specificTime = dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday and hour == 23 and minute == 59 and second == 59
countbar = barssince(specificTime)
plot(countbar)
```

And I'd like to ask how to get the number of bars from last Sunday (I mean Sunday[1]) and previous Sunday (Sunday[2]). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is assume this question is solved by [How to find the number of bars from the last Monday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598003/how-to-find-the-number-of-bars-from-the-last-monday-tradingview)

Comment: Yes. Thank you again for your help. The answer for this question is no longer needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of bars from the last Monday ? tradingview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598003/how-to-find-the-number-of-bars-from-the-last-monday-tradingview)