# How to find the number of bars from the last Monday ? tradingview

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading

Please tell me how to find the number of bars from a previous date.

i.e today is Friday 12-Mar-2021 and Im on the chart of 1 minute timeframe

How to know the number of bars from Monday 8-Mar-2021 00:00:00 ?

And from Monday 1-Mar-2021 00:00:00

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Number of bars from date", "Bars", true)

var int     i_date_start = input(timestamp("2021-03-08"), "Start date", input.time)

var int     bar_index_start = na
var int     bar_count       = na

if na(bar_index_start) and time >= i_date_start
    bar_index_start := bar_index
    
if barstate.islast
    bar_count := bar_index - bar_index_start
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Bar count = " + tostring(bar_count))

plot(na)
```

Edit 1, in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598003/how-to-find-the-number-of-bars-from-the-last-monday-tradingview/66612401?noredirect=1#comment117755505_66612401).

```
//@version=4
study("Number of bars from date", "Bars", true)

var int     bar_index_start = na
var int     bar_count       = na
var bool    start_found     = false

if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
    if not start_found
        bar_index_start := bar_index
        start_found := true
else
    start_found := false

if barstate.islast
    bar_count := bar_index - bar_index_start
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Bar count = " + tostring(bar_count))

plot(na)
```

Edit 2, in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598003/how-to-find-the-number-of-bars-from-the-last-monday-tradingview/66612401?noredirect=1#comment117764624_66612401)

```
//@version=4
study("Number of bars from date", "Bars", true)

int         occurrence = input(2, "Number of mondays ago", minval=1)

var int     bar_index_start = na
var int     bar_count       = na
var bool    start_found     = false
var int[]   bar_indexes     = array.new_int()
var label   lbl             = label.new(na, na, "", style=label.style_label_left)

if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
    if not start_found
        array.unshift(bar_indexes, bar_index)
        start_found := true
else
    start_found := false

if barstate.islast
    if array.size(bar_indexes) >= occurrence
        bar_count := bar_index - array.get(bar_indexes, occurrence-1)
    else
        bar_count := na

    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(lbl, "Bar count since\n" +  tostring(occurrence) + " mondays ago:\n" + tostring(bar_count))

plot(na)
```

Comment: But I just want to get the number of bars from the last Monday, not from the specified Monday. What I typed in the question is just an example. If in the next month, I use this code, it wont work. I need it automatically, I cannot set the start date manually.

Comment: Updated my answer. See Edit 1.

Comment: It works perfectly. I appreciate your help. How about getting the number of bars from the Monday before the last Monday? I mean, 2 week ago.

Comment: Updated my answer. See Edit 2.